# && operator for double

Tags: c#

I need abit of help with an if statement and operators. How could I do this:

```
double AgePenalty = 0;
if (AgeOfCustomer <= 21)
{
    AgePenalty = 15;
}
if (AgeOfCustomer <= 30 && AgeOfCustomer => 21) // cant use && operator with double
{
    AgePenalty = 10;
}
```

This just says if the customer is younger than 21 apply a certain price tag; if the customer is between the ages of 21 and 25 apply smaller price tag etc.

Comment: In future, when you have code giving a compile-time error, please include the error in your question.

Comment: Cmon @JungleBoogie, it's *Summer of Love*, you know? That paragraph wasn't necessary

Comment: Haha I know man! Just having a gentle poke at the good old giant! Im sure he will smile :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not `&&` that's the problem - it's your greater-than-or-equal-to operator, which is `>=`, not `=>`.

```
if (AgeOfCustomer <= 30 && AgeOfCustomer >= 21)
```

`=>` is used for [lambda expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).

(It's not clear why you thought this was related to doubles particularly...)

Comment: @AndreCalil: Nope, it gave a compile-time error (which should have been included in the question, of course).

Comment: The error related to this was was `Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'double'` hence the title.

Comment: Looks like the compiler was getting the lamba result as a bool, that's why you can't logically test double and bool together

Comment: @JungleBoogie: That's *very* strange - it's not the error I saw when I tried to compile something similar. Are you sure the code was *exactly* as you posted?

Comment: @JonSkeet uploaded a screeny into the question (p.s hope you dont mind the humour but your famous!) sorry didnt capture the ageofcustomer but its just a double.

Comment: I just tried this code and I got a syntax error, I can't even try to compile it. Well, anyway, mystery is solved. Thanks guys.

Comment: @GPS: Please don't use comments for this purpose. Your comment is irrelevant to this question and answer.

Comment: @GPS: No, I don't have time to look now, and there are already feature requests. Also, please try to communicate using full words. It's not like you were anywhere near the character limit.

Answer (score 10):

Your check `AgeOfCustomer => 21` is wrong, it should be : `AgeOfCustomer >= 21`
Just change your `if` statement to

```
  if (AgeOfCustomer <= 30 && AgeOfCustomer >= 21)
```

Answer (score 2):

Better write in the following way

```
double AgePenalty = 0;
        if (AgeOfCustomer <= 21)
        {
            AgePenalty = 15;
        }
        else if (AgeOfCustomer <= 30) // as check is done for 21 already.
        {
            AgePenalty = 10;
        }
```

The above code is little optimized.